# MessageBox only showing after form is closed

Tags: .net, winforms, powershell, user-interface

Creating a simple GUI to run a custom function with a given username as an argument.

After the search button is clicked, I need to return the result of my custom function to the user. Preferably without closing the whole thing and allowing them to search again but it's my first time building a GUI

```
import-module "{path to my custom module}"



#region Prereqs
[reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") | Out-Null
#endregion

#region Create Window with textbox and button
$searchForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$unameTextBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$searchButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button


$unameTextBox.Location = '23,23'
$unameTextBox.Size = '150,23'
$unameTextBox.Text = 'Enter username...'

$searchButton.Text = 'Search'
$searchButton.Location = '196,23'


$searchForm.Controls.Add($unameTextBox)
$searchForm.Controls.Add($searchButton)
$searchForm.Text = 'Lit hold search'
$searchForm.ShowDialog()

#function takes 1 argument (uname), performs AD lookup and returns True/False
$status = (Get-MyCustomFunction $unameTextBox.Text)
$searchButton.Add_Click([System.Windows.Forms.Messagebox]::Show($status))

#endregion
```

I expect the message box to pop up after the search button is clicked. Instead it shows up only after the form has been closed. Ideally I would like to keep the form open and allow for additional searches. Maybe there is a better option than messagebox to display a simple message?

Edit:

I'm getting the following error now if that provides additional context...

```
Cannot convert argument "value", with value: "OK", for "add_Click" to type "System.EventHandler": "Cannot convert value "OK" to type "System.EventHandler". Error: "Invalid cast from 
'System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult' to 'System.EventHandler'.""
At C:\Modules\lithold.ps1:33 char:1
+ $searchButton.Add_Click([System.Windows.Forms.Messagebox]::Show($stat ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodArgumentConversionInvalidCastArgument
```

Comment: Move the line `$searchForm.ShowDialog()` down as last line. Below that add `$searchForm.Dispose()` .

Comment: If I move that line below the ````$searchButton.Add_Click([System.Windows.Forms.Messagebox]::Show($status))````

It then shows the messagebox before the Search button has been clicked. It also executes the function with placeholder text since it has not received the user input yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add your handler for click before calling `ShowDialog` (basically where you setup that button) and it has to be added this way:

```
$searchButton.Add_Click(
  {
    $status = (Get-MyCustomFunction $unameTextBox.Text)
    [System.Windows.Forms.Messagebox]::Show($status)
  }
)
```

More info for example here: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/25911.how-to-add-a-powershell-gui-event-handler-part-1.aspx

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked. I had tried that originally but I did not have the ````ShowDialog()```` at the end.

Is it easy to allow 'Enter' to trigger the button after filling the textBox?